# Why do I keep getting "[eslint] Delete `CR` [prettier/prettier]"?

Tags: visual-studio-code, newline, prettier, carriage-return, eslintrc

I am using VS Code with Prettier 1.7.2 and ESLint 1.7.0.
After every newline I get:

```
[eslint] Delete `CR` [prettier/prettier]
```

This is the `.eslintrc.json`:

```json
{
  "extends": ["airbnb", "plugin:prettier/recommended"],
  "env": {
    "jest": true,
    "browser": true
  },
  "rules": {
    "import/no-extraneous-dependencies": "off",
    "import/prefer-default-export": "off",
    "no-confusing-arrow": "off",
    "linebreak-style": "off",
    "arrow-parens": ["error", "as-needed"],
    "comma-dangle": [
      "error",
      {
        "arrays": "always-multiline",
        "objects": "always-multiline",
        "imports": "always-multiline",
        "exports": "always-multiline",
        "functions": "ignore"
      }
    ],
    "no-plusplus": "off"
  },
  "parser": "babel-eslint",
  "plugins": ["react"],
  "globals": {
    "browser": true,
    "$": true,
    "before": true,
    "document": true
  }
}
```

The `.prettierrc` file:

```json
{
  "printWidth": 80,
  "tabWidth": 2,
  "semi": true,
  "singleQuote": true,
  "trailingComma": "es5",
  "bracketSpacing": true,
  "jsxBracketSameLine": false,
}
```

How can I get rid of this error?

Comment: Take a look at your .eslintrc.js file. removing `'plugin:prettier/recommended'` from the extends array should fix the issue.

Comment: You may try disabling ESLint VSCode extension

Answer (score 1182):

Try setting the `"endOfLine":"auto"` in your **.prettierrc** (or .prettierrc.json) file (inside the object)

Or set

```
"prettier/prettier": [
  "error",
  {
    "endOfLine": "auto"
  }
]
```

inside the `rules` object of the **eslintrc** file.

If you are using Windows machine `endOfLine` can be "crlf" basing on your git config.

Comment: Changing the `.eslintrc` file worked for me, but not the `.prettierrc` file. No idea why or what the difference is (I'm new to all the tags on the OP).

Comment: My guess is that you might need Prettier extension in the VS Code. The prettierrc will only be valid in that scenario.

Comment: changing the end of line sequence from `CRLF` to `LF` worked for me, on a windows machine

Comment: For a newbie like me, this is how it is to be done. Open `.eslintrc.json` present in your root directory (`frontend`). After changes it will look as under: `{
  "extends": ["react-app", "prettier"],
  "plugins": ["prettier"],
  "rules": {
    "prettier/prettier": ["error", { "endOfLine": "auto" }]
  }
}
`

Comment: FYI: a restart is required for the changes to take effect on VSCode.

Comment: I created a file .prettierrc.json with "endOfLine":"auto", as that is a valid filename and nothing was working. 2 hours later, I decided to rename the file to .prettierrc to rules things out, but I couldn't. -the file already existed! doh. and that gets picked up first!

Comment: for me it worked after a window reload with ```ESlint: fix all auto-fixable problem``` command for eslint file

Comment: In continuation to the comment from @SimpleGuy : after completion of the steps run `npm run lint -- --fix` helps.

Comment: The key as @Sangimed mentioned is to restart VS Code if you place any Prettier rules in the prettierrc file. If the rule are placed in the Eslint file, a restart shouldn't be needed.

Comment: Where is .prettierrc (or .prettierrc.json) located? I can't find any such file.

Comment: Thanks for saving me some serious headache!

Answer (score 745):

Change this setting on VSCode.

[image: An image showing the status bar at the bottom of the VSCode window. An arrow points to the 'LF' indicator; clicking on this option brings up a menu where you can select between LF and CLRF.]

Comment: This would fix the problem, but only till you opened some other source file with CRLF.  Above answer is more effective.

Comment: Besides changing `CRLF` to `LF` within VSCode, `git` might be doing auto conversion under the hood. If you chose `checkout Windows-style` when installing, it converts source code you clone to `CRLF`. So reinstalling `git` and choose `checkout as-is, commit Unix-style` will fix it.

Answer (score 257):

In my windows machine, I solved this by adding the below code snippet in `rules` object of `.eslintrc.js` file present in my current project's directory.

```
    "prettier/prettier": [
      "error",
      {
        "endOfLine": "auto"
      },
    ],
```

This worked on my Mac as well

Answer (score 85):

## Solution

```
git config --global core.autocrlf false
```

After global configuration, you need to pull the code again.

## Root cause of the problem:

The culprit is `git`, a configuration property of `core.autocrlf`

For historical reasons, the line breaks of the text file on `windows` and `linux` are different.

- `Windows` At the time of line break, carriage return is used at the same time `CR(carriage-return character)` and line breaks `LF(linefeed character)`
- `Mac` and `Linux` only use the newline character `LF`
- Old version of `Mac` uses carriage return `CR`

Therefore, there will be incompatibility problems when text files are created and used in different systems.

When I clone code on `Windows`, `autocrlf` is **true** as default and then each line of the file is automatically converted to `CRLF`. If you do not make any changes to the file, `eslint` delete `CR` by `pre-commit` since `git` automatically convert `CRLF` to `LF`.

## Reference

https://developpaper.com/solution-to-delete-%E2%90%8Deslint-prettier-prettier-error/

Comment: This solution would break cross-platform development - you'd be able to push a mix or LF/CR/CRLF to the repo. I suggest not to use it unless you work alone, and only ever on one type of OS (Linux/Mac/Windows). A good config for a team is to use autocrlf=true and just configure the linting tools to respect the EOL characters of the platform they run on, as in the other answers ("endOfLine": "auto"). What is worse is that you suggest to set autocrlf=false GLOBALLY, I think if it ever needs to be done, it should always be per-repo, otherwise all your new repos have a problem from the get go.

Answer (score 75):

in the file .eslintrc.json
in side roles add this code it will solve this issue

```
      "rules": {
    "prettier/prettier": ["error",{
      "endOfLine": "auto"}
    ]

  }
```

Comment: This is what I was looking for - ppl didn't mention that it must be inside "rules" otherwise it won't help at all

Answer (score 53):

If the above code is not working for you try these two steps.

1.
in the file .eslintrc.json **inside rules object** add this code it will solve this issue

```
 "prettier/prettier": ["error",{
      "endOfLine": "auto"}
    ]
```

2
Change dev server --fix

```
npm run dev
```

To

```
npm run dev --fix
```

OR

```
npm run lint -- --fix
yarn run lint -- --fix
```

Comment: after adding code to file, dont forget to commit or run `npm run lint -- --fix`

Answer (score 48):

As you can see add this into .eslintrc works!

[image]

```json
"prettier/prettier": ["error", {
    "endOfLine": "auto" }
],
```

Comment: Would be an even better answer if you pasted searchable and copy/pasteable source code, rather than an image :-)

Comment: This is the code, it worked for me "prettier/prettier": [
  "error", {
    "endOfLine": "auto"
  }
]

Answer (score 33):

Fixed - My .eslintrc.js looks like this:

```
module.exports = {
  root: true,
  extends: '@react-native-community',
  rules: {'prettier/prettier': ['error', {endOfLine: 'auto'}]},
};
```

Comment: Thanks fellow react-native user

Answer (score 28):

Try this. It works for me:

> yarn run lint --fix

or

> npm run lint -- --fix

Answer (score 21):

I know this is old but I just encountered the issue in my team (some mac, some linux, some windows , all vscode).

solution was to set the line ending in vscode's settings:

`.vscode/settings.json`

```
{
    "files.eol": "\n",
}
```

https://qvault.io/2020/06/18/how-to-get-consistent-line-breaks-in-vs-code-lf-vs-crlf/

Answer (score 15):

In the .eslintrc file add the following:

- `extends: ['prettier']` and `plugins: ['prettier']`
- `rules: {'prettier/prettier': ['error', {endOfLine: 'auto'}]}`

In .prettierrc remove this:

- `endOfLine: 'auto'`

It works for me.

Answer (score 14):

npm run lint -- --fix

Run this command this worked for me

Comment: For me aswell thank you!

Answer (score 13):

Add this to your **.prettierrc** file and open the **VSCODE**

```
"endOfLine": "auto"
```

Answer (score 13):

Fixed: My eslintrc.js some rule look like this:

```
rules: {
    'prettier/prettier': ['error', { "endOfLine": "auto"}, { usePrettierrc: true }],  // Use our .prettierrc file as source
    'react/react-in-jsx-scope': 'off',
    'react/prop-types': 'off',
    'simple-import-sort/imports': 'error',
    "simple-import-sort/exports": "error"
}
```

Answer (score 11):

I am using git+vscode+windows+vue, and after read the eslint document: https://eslint.org/docs/rules/linebreak-style

Finally fix it by:

add `*.js text eol=lf` to `.gitattributes`

then run `vue-cli-service lint --fix`

Answer (score 10):

Add these below rule in .eslintrc file and **then restart your project.**

```
rules: {
    'prettier/prettier': ['error', { "endOfLine": "auto"}, { usePrettierrc: true }],  
}
```

Answer (score 10):

Add **below** line in the **".eslintrc.js"** file

```
rules: {'prettier/prettier': ['error', {endOfLine: 'auto'}]}
```

e.g

[image]

Answer (score 7):

I was having the same problem in my nest js app . Adding the below code to `.eslintrc.js`rules and then running `yarn run lint --fix` fixed the issue .

```
'prettier/prettier': [
  'error',
  {
    endOfLine: 'auto',
  },
],
```

and my `.eslintrc.js` rules looks something  like this..

```
 rules: {
'@typescript-eslint/interface-name-prefix': 'off',
'@typescript-eslint/explicit-function-return-type': 'off',
'@typescript-eslint/explicit-module-boundary-types': 'off',
'@typescript-eslint/no-explicit-any': 'off',
'prettier/prettier': [
  'error',
  {
    endOfLine: 'auto',
  },
],
```

},

Answer (score 7):

***Solution***

**1. Disable auto conversion git setting**

> git --global config core.autocrlf false

**2. Remove old cache data**

> git rm --cached -r .

**3. Reset git files**

> git reset --hard

Answer (score 7):

if you have already checked out the code

```
git config --global core.autocrlf input 


git rm --cached -r . 


git reset --hard
```

Comment: this would delete all your local git changes, be carefull to execute these commands.

Comment: Worked for me on windows

Answer (score 6):

In my case I am using windows OS and git code supports in Mac and getting converted to CRLF
run below Command in cmd prompt to stop files getting converted to CRLF:
[image]

```
git config --global core.autocrlf input
```

Checkout the code again and open Visual Studio Code again and run your scripts again. It worked for me.

Comment: why `input`? How else this suggestion is different from that by koko-js478?

Answer (score 6):

I tried everything here and for me, I needed to manage prettier config extension through icon extensions > prettier > small engine > extensions settings > Prettier: End Of Line > set to auto.

After adding these two lines in my settings.json

```
"eslint.run": "onSave",
"editor.formatOnSave": true,
```

I was able to use the config below inside .eslintrc.js rule.

```
"prettier/prettier": ["error", {
    "endOfLine":"auto"
}],
```

Answer (score 6):

Check the right-hand side of VS Code's status bar at the bottom where it shows information such as line and column, spaces, text encoding (UTF-8 etc). You should see a `Select End Of Line Sequence` status display (either **LF** or **CRLF**) that you can click on to change. Make sure you haven't manually changed this to something that conflicts with what you wish Prettier to use.

Answer (score 6):

The best solution is to use [.editorconfig](https://editorconfig.org/). Especially if you are working with a team with different type OS. So disabling prettier in .eslintrc is not a good option at all.

Install .editorconfig from your vscode extension. Create a **.editorconfig** file in your project root directory and it to your `.gitignore` file so it won't bother your teammates.

Add this to your **.editorconfig** file or choose what workflow settings you need from the [documentation](https://editorconfig.org/).

```
[*]
end_of_line = lf
```

This will save your file automatically to EOL type `lf` instead of `crlf` in windows. Vise versa if using mac. Or depends on the project workflow setup.

The root cause is windows is default to crlf. So every time you try to create a file you will face this prettier `Delete 'cr'` error.

***In Addition***

If all the files you got from git contains `Delete 'cr'`.

1. Delete your project
2. Reinstall your git and choose  **checkout as-is, commit Unix-style line endings**
3. Clone your project from repo again
4. Use the .editorconfig set up above

Comment: the best answer so far, thanks

Comment: Best answer. Addresses the core problem.

Answer (score 6):

```
rules: {
            "prettier/prettier": [
                "error",
                {
                    endOfLine: "auto",
                },
            ],
        }
```

**RESTART YOUR VSCODE** after adding this in your project's '**.eslintrc.js**' file.

And also add

```
module.exports = { 
  endOfLine: 'auto',
  // keep other values 
}
```

in your project's '**.prettierrc.js**'

Comment: `module.exports = {  endOfLine: 'auto'}` works

Comment: Lots of ways do to this I see here.  This one worked for me in my RN project.

Answer (score 5):

In project your add code here in file **`.eslintrc.js`**:

```
 'prettier/prettier': [
        'error',
        {
            endOfLine: 'auto',
        },
    ],
```

And it will fix it

[image]

Answer (score 4):

## Error appears when I pull code from git, and this work for me:

### STEP 1:

`git config --global core.autocrlf false`

### STEP 2:

- delete your current folder

### STEP 3:

- pull code from git again
- try running command again

Comment: git config --global core.autocrlf false

this command works very well, solving the LF issue on vs code

Comment: If you're working on different projects with different configurations you can set the flag locally for that repo by omitting the `--global` flag. Also, you don't need to delete the entire repo and clone it again, just resetting the branch to origin should work.

Answer (score 4):

If you need to use with .prettierrc.js:

```
module.exports = {
    ...[config params],
    endOfLine: 'auto',
};
```

Note! Not in `rules` or `prettier/prettier`.

Info here https://prettier.io/docs/en/options.html#end-of-line

Answer (score 4):

executing eslint for linting and fixing solved my issue.

`eslint . --ext .vue,.js,.jsx,.cjs,.mjs,.ts,.tsx,.cts,.mts --fix --ignore-path .gitignore`

or if you have lint script: `npm run lint`

Comment: Alternatively to this, you can use `npm run lint` if your project haves npm linting setup, for some reason on my vue 3 project vscode just get bugged ocasionally with these kind of errors as mention by OP

Answer (score 3):

In the root open the .editorconfig file and change:

`end_of_line = lf`

to

`end_of_line = auto`

This should fix it for new files.

Answer (score 3):

What worked for me was:

1. Update prettier to version 2.2.1 (latest version at the moment) as Roberto LL suggested. To do it execute

> npm update prettier

2. Execute lint fix as Hakan suggested (This will modify all files in the project to convert line ending to LF).

> npm run lint -- --fix

**It was not necessary to change .eslintrc and .prettierrc files!**

Comment: prettier was up-to-date in my machine, But running npm run lint -- --fix fixed the problem.

Comment: This work for me with nestjs and windows, thanks!

Comment: I tried a lot of other solutions proposed here but only this resolved the issue.

Answer (score 3):

edit your .eslintrc.json file and update "prettier/prettier" value shown below.

I face same problem and fixed using below changes.

```
"prettier/prettier": [
    "error", {
         "singleQuote": true,
         "parser": "flow" 
    }
],
```

Answer (score 2):

I upgraded to "prettier": "^2.2.0" and error went away

Answer (score 2):

There is no need to ignore linter's rule. Just auto-fix it

```
npm install -g prettier
prettier -w .\webpack.config.js # or other file
```

Answer (score 2):

Delete this line from the file .prettierrc

```
 "endOfLine": "crlf"
```

Answer (score 1):

Its work for me

step-1
React js root directory find .eslintrc file

Step-2
find in .eslintrc

```
"prettier/prettier": [
  2,
  {
    "printWidth": 100,
    "singleQuote": true,
    "trailingComma": "none",
    "tabWidth": 2
  }
]
```

replace with

```
"prettier/prettier": [
  "error",
  {
    "endOfLine": "auto"
  }
]
```

save file and then run

```
npm start
```

Answer (score 1):

Just run this command: `npx eslint --fix user-repository.ts`.

This command will automatically resolved all the issues.

and this will also show the actual warnings, which are not automatically getting resolved. resolve that using the intellisense and `[eslint] Delete CR [prettier/prettier]` will diappear.

Answer (score 0):

All the answers above are correct, but when I use windows and **disable the Prettier ESLint extension** `rvest.vs-code-prettier-eslint` the issue will be fixed.

Answer (score 0):

For those using @vue/prettier there may be a conflict between it and eslint which results in this error. Despite being installed along with vue cli, @vue/prettier was a [temporary solution](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-prettier) until prettier accepted vue natively and that [has already been done](https://github.com/prettier/prettier/pull/5259). The problem can be solved by switching to just 'prettier'

Answer (score 0):

You need add rules the file .eslintrc

```
"extends": ["plugin:prettier/recommended"],
"plugins": ["prettier"],
"rules": {
 "prettier/prettier": ["error"],
 "@typescript-eslint/no-unsafe-call": "off",
 "@typescript-eslint/unbound-method": "off",
 "@typescript-eslint/no-explicit-any": "off",
 "@typescript-eslint/no-unsafe-member-access": "off",
 "@typescript-eslint/no-unsafe-assignment": "off",
 "@typescript-eslint/no-empty-function": "off",
 "@angular-eslint/no-empty-lifecycle-method": "off",
 "@typescript-eslint/no-unused-vars": ["off"],
 "@typescript-eslint/require-await": "off",
 "@typescript-eslint/ban-types": "off"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you already added the rule

```
"prettier/prettier": [
      "error",
      {
        "endOfLine": "auto"
      },
    ],
```

in your `.prettierrc.js` but the issue isn't fixed, just restart the node server. `npm start`.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using vscode, just press ctrl + . and it will fix it

Answer (score -2):

I tried all these answers given in this question but none of them completely fixed the issue.
But after trying & searching for the solution i got the solution from a [youtube video](https://youtu.be/CrYWH0KP2-A?t=101) that says, to add the following lines in your `.eslintrc.js` (Or whatever es lint config) file...

```
rules: {
    // rules...
    "prettier/prettier": 0
}
```

This setting removed all prettier related errors.

Comment: This is not a viable solution in my opinion, since you're just bypassing prettier rules here.

Comment: then just stop using eslint altogether

Answer (score -4):

So you can disable or uninstall the 'eslint' extension for solve this problem, it worked for me.