# Laravel vue - error Delete `␍` prettier/prettier , potentially fixable with the `--fix` option

Tags: laravel, vue.js, npm

npm run watch returing this error
    181 problems (181 errors, 0 warnings)
      181 errors and 0 warnings potentially fixable with the `--fix` option.

```
 @ ./resources/js/backend/router/index.js 15:0-41 160:21-29
 @ ./resources/js/backend/app.js
 @ multi ./resources/js/backend/app.js ./resources/sass/backend/app.scss

ERROR in ./resources/js/vue-i18n-config.js
Module Error (from ./node_modules/eslint-loader/index.js):

\resources\js\vue-i18n-config.js
   1:4   error  Delete `␍`  prettier/prettier
   2:18  error  Delete `␍`  prettier/prettier
   3:4   error  Delete `␍`  prettier/prettier
   4:22  error  Delete `␍`  prettier/prettier
   5:1   error  Delete `␍`  prettier/prettier
   6:4   error  Delete `␍`  prettier/prettier
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why do I keep getting Delete 'cr' \[prettier/prettier\]?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53516594/why-do-i-keep-getting-delete-cr-prettier-prettier)

Comment: I do recommend to consider @yuriy636 suggestion of reading.

Answer (score 7):

Possibly this help you: Set `` "endOfLine":"auto" in your `.prettierrc` file `` then restart server and run `npm run lint -- --fix`.

Comment: This did not work for me. I do recommend the reading of the answer for https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53516594/why-do-i-keep-getting-delete-cr-prettier-prettier

Answer (score 0):

Try this probably it will help you.

1. Create this file '.prettierrc.js' in your root directory. And add this code in that file.
   `module.exports = { semi: false, trailingComma: "all", singleQuote: true, tabWidth: 4 };`
2. Open VScode preferences -> setting -> Edit in setting.json [image]
   And add this code `"files.eol": "\r\n",`
3. Open this file '.eslintrc.js', and add this code
   `rules: {'prettier/prettier': ['off', { singleQuote: true }]},`

> Before running the server, run this `npx prettier --write . '!**/*.{js,jsx,vue}'`, after execute this run, start the server.