# Error Delete 'CR' prettier/prettier Visual Studio Code

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, nuxt.js

After installing Nuxt.js with this command `npx create-nuxt-app <myapp>` everything working fine, but when I tried to change the styles code on `layout/default.vue` I got these errors:

> 241:9  error  Insert `⏎`  prettier/prettier

I'm using Visual Studio Code, so I changed the settings from `Preferences > settings > Extensions > Vetur`, I changed the `Format > Default Formatter: CSS = none` and `Default Formatter: HTML = none`.

Still, the problem persists. I tried to fix using this command I found on GitHub `npm run lint -- --fix` and it worked, but every time I add a new file to the project, I got the error again! So funny! I'm new in Nuxt.js.

I have another's projects using only VueJS and everything working fine.

Help! Thanks in advance!

Comment: I recommend the reading of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53516594/why-do-i-keep-getting-delete-cr-prettier-prettier?r=SearchResults&s=1|315.4737

Answer (score 3):

In the root open the .editorconfig file and change:

```
end_of_line = lf
```

to

```
end_of_line = auto
```

This should fix it for new files.

Answer (score 0):

to resolve this issue, use below command

> yarn lint --fix

if you have not installed **yarn** yet then install the **yarn** first.

Answer (score 0):

So I was getting the error when I tried to commit.
I did this and it skipped the verification:

```
git commit -m "" --no-verify
```

I also followed this for VSCode
https://medium.com/@csmunuku/windows-and-linux-eol-sequence-configure-vs-code-and-git-37be98ef71df

> VS Code => Settings => Files: EoL
> And choose “\n” as EoL character if you would like your files to have Unix Style line endings and choose “\r\n” if you would like your files to have Windows Style line endings.