# How can I solve the prettier/prettier problem

Tags: eslint, prettier-eslint

I'm using `nuxtjs`, and I installed `eslint` on my project, and upon using `npm run dev`, I get a bombardment of errors. How can I fix this:

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why do I keep getting "\[eslint\] Delete \`CR\` \[prettier/prettier\]"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53516594/why-do-i-keep-getting-eslint-delete-cr-prettier-prettier)

Answer (score 18):

This error is related to [Windows Line endings](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline#Representation) being different from Unix ones. Try running `npx prettier --write .` on your project's directory. This command will tell prettier to fix simple errors (such as this one) when found.

To prevent this error from happening again you can either [set "end-of-line" to auto](https://prettier.io/docs/en/options.html#end-of-line) on your `.prettierrc` file or try setting line endings to "Unix"/LF on your editor: [instructions for VSCode](https://qvault.io/2020/06/18/how-to-get-consistent-line-breaks-in-vs-code-lf-vs-crlf/) and for [IntelliJ-based editors](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/configuring-line-endings-and-line-separators.html)

Comment: Thank you ❤️. This simple answer helped me a lot.

Answer (score 0):

in your `.prettierrc` file, add this: "endOfLine": "auto"

Comment: This is just repeating what has been said in a [much earlier answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65400943/10871073).