# Get rid of error: Delete `␍⏎` eslint (prettier/prettier), and allow use double `cr` Visual Studio Code1.56.2 on Windows 10

Tags: visual-studio-code, eslint, prettier

I want to **use double `␍`** ("carriage return"  || "Enter" key) to visually separate code-sections,
and **start new chaining form separate line** (even if line length less then 80char).

But  get an error: Delete `␍⏎`eslint (prettier/prettier)

my code snippet:

```html
router.param("id", checkId) //middleware to validate id
`␍`
`␍`
router.route("/")`␍`
  .get(getAllTours)`␍`
  .post(checkBody, createTour)

router.route("/:id")`␍`
  .get(getTour)`␍`
  .patch(updateTour)`␍`
  .delete(deleteTour)
`␍`
`␍`
module.exports = router
```

Tried:
.eslintrc.json

```html
'prettier/prettier': [
  'error',
  {
    'endOfLine': 'auto',
  }
]
```

Answer form https://stackoverflow.com/a/53769213/15580822

and also try the same in my config .prettierrc

All of this did not help. I'm getting the same error continuously...

I do **not** want to disable prettier completely.

But setting **"endOfLine"** in .eslintrc.json** (**"off"** - Never automatically format embedded code.)
completely disable warnings from prettier

```html
{ 
'endOfLine': 'off',
}
```

**My question:**
what it actually does?
Do I disable prettier completely?

I can not find an answer here or Google...

Any thoughts how to get rid of this error and still **use prettier**?

Comment: The solution you mentioned up there suggests to set the "endOfLine":"auto" in your .prettierrc file (inside the object). Did you try that?

Comment: And you have to restart VSCode to see the effect.

Comment: If you did this and it didn't work, you probably need to restart your VSCode. It will be fixed.

Answer (score 23):

Answer is on the comments above, I had the same issue and after a bit of trial and error it was solved with:

On my `.eslintrc.js`

```
endOfLine: 'off'
```

And the `.prettierrc.js`

```
endOfLine: 'auto'
```

No more issues on the ESLint output, all works fine.

Answer (score 4):

In your **.eslintrc.json**, set like this:

```
...
"prettier/prettier": [
            "error", 
            {
              "endOfLine": "off"
            }
        ]
...
```

after this, the ESLint don't send issues about this.

Answer (score 1):

On .eslintrc.js :

```
  ignorePatterns: ['.eslintrc.js'],
```

**add "*" like this :**

```
  ignorePatterns: ['.eslintrc.js',"*"],
```

works fine !

Answer (score -4):

I solved it by deleting the two files .eslintrc.js and .prettierrc.js, and then just used the Prettier extension in vs code.