# Why I am getting unexpected errors in React JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am started learning React JS. I am getting an unexpected error on the Clock.js file. But I don't understand why I am getting the error.

**Here is a image of my project folder:**

[image]

### Error I'm getting: `Delete ␍ eslintprettier/prettier`

**index.js:**

```js
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import reportWebVitals from './reportWebVitals';

ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);

reportWebVitals();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

**app.js:**

```js
import React from 'react';
import Clock from './components/Clock';

function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      <Clock />
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

**Clock.js:**

```js
import React from 'react';

class Clock extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <h1>
        <span>Time: {new Date().toLocaleTimeString()}</span>
      </h1>
    );
  }
}

export default Clock;
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

**.eslintrc config:**

```
{
  "parserOptions": {
  "ecmaVersion": 12,
  "sourceType": "module",
  "ecmaFeatures": {
    "jsx": true
    }
  },
  "extends": ["plugin:prettier/recommended"],
  
  "plugins": ["prettier"],
  
  "rules": {
    "prettier/prettier": "error"
  }
}
```

**.prettierrc config:**

```
{
  "semi": true,
  "singleQuote": true,
  "tabWidth": 2,
  "useTabs": false
}
```

What is the solution? Please help me to solve the problem.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53516594/why-do-i-keep-getting-delete-cr-prettier-prettier?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why do I keep getting Delete 'cr' \[prettier/prettier\]?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53516594/why-do-i-keep-getting-delete-cr-prettier-prettier). It's complaining about the carriage return.

Comment: Thanks. Solved.

Answer (score -1):

At the very bottom of VSCode where you see `CRLF` click on that and switch it to `LF`