# How to fix Failed to compile -Module Error (from ./node_modules/eslint-loader/index.js): issue?

Tags: vue.js

My pages worked fine. But after sometime it's showing this error. I removed the fontawesome link from html file. I have used jquery in vue js for changing some css style. It worked well though. But now suddenly it's showing lots of this kind of error on the screen. I also removed "@vue/cli-plugin-eslint" from package.json to get rid off it.

C:\New folder\restaurant\src\views\Home.vue
1:11   warning  Delete `␍`                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               prettier/prettier

4:7    warning  Replace `·<div·class="col-md-8·content_body">␍` with `<div·class="col-md-8·content_body">`

**Here is my package.json file:**

```
{
  "name": "restaurant",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "watch": "npm-watch",
    "serve": "vue-cli-service serve",
    "build": "vue-cli-service build",
    "lint": "vue-cli-service lint"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "core-js": "^3.6.5",
    "npm-watch": "^0.11.0",
    "register-service-worker": "^1.7.1",
    "vue": "^3.0.0",
    "vue-router": "^4.0.0-0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@vue/cli-plugin-babel": "~4.5.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-pwa": "~4.5.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-router": "~4.5.0",
    "@vue/cli-service": "~4.5.0",
    "@vue/compiler-sfc": "^3.0.0",
    "@vue/eslint-config-prettier": "^6.0.0",
    "babel-eslint": "^10.1.0",
    "eslint": "^6.7.2",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^3.3.1",
    "eslint-plugin-vue": "^7.0.0",
    "prettier": "^2.2.1",
    "sass": "^1.26.5",
    "sass-loader": "^8.0.2"
  },
  "watch": {
    "build": {
      "patterns": [
        "src"
      ],
      "extensions": "js,jsx"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why do I keep getting Delete 'cr' \[prettier/prettier\]?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53516594/why-do-i-keep-getting-delete-cr-prettier-prettier)

Comment: Yaah thanks! I deleted the jquery function. Now it's working fine.