# Delete `␍`eslintprettier/prettier

Tags: reactjs, git, github, eslint, prettier

Before you mash the duplicate button, I know there are more posts on the same issue and I've tried the solutions to no avail (Please see the last part of my post).

I'm using React 17.0.2, ESLint 8.5.0 and Prettier 2.5.1 and I'm getting the following error in almost every js file.

```
Delete `␍`eslintprettier/prettier
```

This is what it looks like

[image]

This is my .eslintrc.json:

```
{
    "env": {
        "browser": true,
        "es2021": true
    },
    "extends": [
        "eslint:recommended",
        "plugin:react/recommended",
        "plugin:prettier/recommended"
    ],
    "parserOptions": {
        "ecmaFeatures": {
            "jsx": true
        },
        "ecmaVersion": 13,
        "sourceType": "module"
    },
    "plugins": [
        "react"
    ],
    "rules": {
        "react/react-in-jsx-scope": "off"
    }
}
```

I followed this guide to add ESLint and Prettier to my project

https://medium.com/how-to-react/config-eslint-and-prettier-in-visual-studio-code-for-react-js-development-97bb2236b31a

I've tried almost every suggestion from another post about the same issue to no avail...

[Why do I keep getting Delete 'cr' [prettier/prettier]?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53516594/why-do-i-keep-getting-delete-cr-prettier-prettier)

I've used

```
git config --global core.autocrlf false
```

Deleted my project and cloned it again a few times, but no change. I've also tried some of the other suggestions where they edit .eslintrc.json but it either doesn't work or breaks my autoformat.

I'm out of ideas and spent way too much time on this, can anyone tell where I'm going wrong?

Comment: What line-ending setting do you have set in VSCode? (on the bottom bar there should be a button that toggles bwteeen 'CRLF' and 'LF').

Comment: @match Thanks for the suggestion! It was on CRLF, changing it to LF fixes it for the current file. Is there a way to put LF as default so I don't have to change it every time I'm in a different file?

Comment: https://qvault.io/clean-code/line-breaks-vs-code-lf-vs-crlf/

Comment: Added a proper answer - it was a valid question that I've seen people hit by before, and covers the 'other side' - i.e the editor, not the files or git.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Many editors let you change between CRLF and LF line-ending modes.  On VSCode this is a toggle on the bottom menu bar which switches when clicked.

The change the default for all files, edit `settings.json` and add the following at the top:

For default LF:

```
{
    "files.eol": "\n",
}
```

For default CRLF:

```
{
    "files.eol": "\r\n",
}
```

Comment: Thanks again for the help. I'm sure this answer will help someone else in the future as well.

Answer (score 41):

You could easily fix that issue.

In `.eslintrc.json` file, you should configure `rules` option.

Add the following configuration and it will fix the problem.

```
"prettier/prettier": ["error", { "endOfLine": "auto" }]
```