# I got "Delete `CD`" message from eslint error

Tags: node.js, typescript, nestjs, typescript-eslint, prettier-eslint

I'm writing my first lines on Nestjs but when I create my first .ts file I got this error, I don't understand what this means.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution in [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53516594/why-do-i-keep-getting-delete-cr-prettier-prettier) the thing is that you have to change the follow configuration on VSC

[image]