# Got a delete ESlint/Prettier when I create a template

Tags: vue.js, eslint, prettier

[image]

What is the work of prettier?
Note that all the Extension for vue have been install

Comment: It's unclear what you ask about, see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask . In case you wonder why there are end of line fixes from a linter, that's because it's incorrectly the ones from windows

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53516594/why-do-i-keep-getting-delete-cr-prettier-prettier

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing critical here, it's a Prettier error.

You can either fix that one manually or run a format via ESlint or directly via Prettier to fix it (depends of the configuration of your project).

Overall, I recommend this kind of setup overall: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68880413/8816585